# Difference between apt-cache and axi-cache

Tags: apt

What is the difference between `apt-cache` and `axi-cache`?

Because  It seems they gives same result. Also It has same options like:

- `axi-cache search`, `apt-cache search`
- `axi-cache show`, `apt-cache show`
- `axi-cache depends`, `apt-cache depends`
- `axi-cache showpkg`, `apt-cache showpkg` etc.

---

From `man apt-cache`:

> apt-cache - query the APT cache

& From `man axi-cache`:

> axi-cache - query the Apt Xapian Index

So, What is difference in **APT cache** and **APT Xapian Index** ?

What is Xapian Index (stand for, how used, how differs with `apt-cache`)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `apt-cache` only shows the package name and its description. `axi-cache` shows the number of results found, more terms and more tags; all in all it means a more complete description. By using `axi-cache` your chances to find what you are looking for are better because of the more detailed info.

Comment: I have not heard of axi-cache, until now, I'll look it up for myself but it sounds to me, from your answer, that it is like aptitude, which is what I use to search for packages. aptitude search mesa returns all of the mesa packages. aptitude search trusty returns all packages with trusty in name.

Comment: I was right, although there is a lot more to axi-cache... `axi-cache search trusty` returns the packages with trusty in the name, just as aptitude... except aptitude lists them all at once, you must enter `axi-cache more` to see second, third, fourth pages (and so on). It is interesting, learn something new daily... many axi-cache commands refer directly to apt-cache front-end commands (see: axi-cache --help), but you can do `axi-cache last 5` to see last 5 searches or queries again.